# NodeJS server that converts m4a audio blobs into mp3 files works locally, but not on server

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg

I'm experiencing issues when running my NodeJS server on a remote host. The server is supposed to convert webm and m4a audio files to mp3 files using the [ffmpeg-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg) and [fluent-ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg) (npm) packages.

The original files are created using the MediaRecorder Web API. Chrome supports the 'audio/webm' (webm) mimeType, but Safari only supports 'audio/mp4' (m4a). When I run my node server locally, it converts both the m4a files and the webm files just fine. When I host my node server, the webm files are converted without problems, but the m4a files specifically return as 1 second audio files. They're all 8398 bytes in size. You can hear the start of the recording in the 1 second file as well. I'm completely lost on what the issue could be, especially since it works fine when the node server runs locally (through the terminal).

Does anyone have any ideas? I checked both the node version as well as all the packages; they are identical. The server doesn't give any errors or feedback. It behaves as if everything is going fine.

I simplified the code and selected just the part that converts the file. Here's the code that converts the m4a file to an mp3. It's triggered 2 seconds after the server starts up (the file is already there on startup in this testing scenario):

```
const convertFunc = () => {
    ffmpeg('./public/testfile.m4a')
        .output('./public/testfile.mp3')
        .on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            console.log('Conversion completed successfully');
        })
        .run()
}
```

Comment: code sample? where is the server hosted? what type of host? please provide more details

Comment: The server is hosted on a service called "mijn.host" which is a Dutch provider. It's not focused on hosting NodeJS apps, but it does provide the option. The code is really quite standard. To simplify it, I basically just convert an m4a file to a mp3 file on startup (of the server) and it gives the same result. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Maybe you are using different  Node versions. Can you align them?

Comment: I double checked; node versions are the same on both systems. Haven't found any differences between the two systems that could be relevant to this issue. Going to run more tests tomorrow.